# Ignore nulls from multi-select input controls?

Tags: jasper-reports, jasperserver

I have a report with several input controls that are used to populate another input control.

My input controls:

1. **GPI** - a multi-select input control that has product codes. The parameter is a collection.
2. **NAME_LOOKUP** - a single-value text box where the user can type a product name. The parameter is a string.
3. **NDC** - a list of drug codes that obtains values based on what is input in **GPI** and **NAME_LOOKUP**.

The query that populates **NDC** has this *WHERE* clause:

```sql
 WHERE (
   REGEXP_LIKE(DESCRIPTION, $P{name_lookup}, 'i')
   OR REGEXP_LIKE(NDC, $P{name_lookup}, 'i')
       )
   OR ($X{IN, GPI, gpi})
```

It works as the *`$X`* syntax is designed to -- if the user doesn't select a **GPI** value from the list, my **NDC** input control shows all drug codes. However, I only want to show drug codes when a value is actually selected from the **GPI** input control.

When I try

```sql
 WHERE (
   REGEXP_LIKE(DESCRIPTION, $P{name_lookup}, 'i')
   OR REGEXP_LIKE(NDC, $P{name_lookup}, 'i')
       )
   OR ($X{IN, GPI, gpi} AND $P{gpi} IS NOT NULL)
```

I get an invalid column type in *JasperReports Server* for the **NDC** input control.

When I try

```sql
 WHERE (
   REGEXP_LIKE(DESCRIPTION, $P{name_lookup}, 'i')
   OR REGEXP_LIKE(NDC, $P{name_lookup}, 'i')
       )
   OR ($X{IN, GPI, gpi} AND $P!{gpi} IS NOT NULL)
```

I get a missing expression error.

What can I do to limit the **NDC** input control's results to just the selected **GPI**, and not all results?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I just found this while experiencing the same problem, I finally solved it using a second parameter holding the lenght of the list:

```
<parameter name="potentially_empty_list" class="java.util.Collection"/>
<parameter name="num_of_list_elements" class="java.lang.Integer" isForPrompting="false">
        <defaultValueExpression>
<![CDATA[$P{potentially_empty_list}.size()]]>
</defaultValueExpression>
</parameter>
```

And the SQL query would then be:

```
[... select etc...]
WHERE $X{IN,mysql_column_name, ist}
AND $P{num_of_list_elements} > 0
```

which for an empty list would be sent to mysql as:

```
WHERE 0 = 0 #(that's how jasper parses $X{IN..} for an empty collection
AND 0 > 0   # don't match anything :)
```

Answer (score 0):

There is an interesting alternative because $X{NOTIN, ...} also evaluates to 0=0 in case of empty list.

Therefore you can do like this:

```
($X{IN, cs.companyid, companyIds} 
  AND NOT 
  ($X{NOTIN, cs.companyid, companyIds}))
```